# Is it possible to find all concrete types of generic method calls in .NET code?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection, code-generation, analysis

I'm writing a C# code generator for serialization of objects in order to send them over the network.

The starting point is this (simplified):

```cs
public static partial class Serialization
{
    public static void Serialize<T>(in T value, DataStream stream)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException($"Don't know how to serialize type {typeof(T)}!");
    }

    public static void Deserialize<T>(out T target, DataStream stream)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException($"Don't know how to deserialize type {typeof(T)}!");
    }
}
```

Now the serialization code generator will generate additional non-generic `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods for all types that need serialization, like this for a struct `Vector3` with public `float` fields `x`, `y` and `z`:

```cs
public static partial class Serialization
{
    // automatically generated method
    public static void Serialize(in Vector3 value, DataStream stream)
    {
        stream.Write(value.x);
        stream.Write(value.y);
        stream.Write(value.z);
    }

    // automatically generated method
    public static void Deserialize(out Vector3 target, DataStream stream)
    {
        target.x = stream.ReadFloat();
        target.y = stream.ReadFloat();
        target.z = stream.ReadFloat();
    }
}
```

The generic methods shown in the beginning are only there to prevent compiler errors in cases where the serialization code has not (yet) been generated for a type. I need the code to compile because otherwise I can't use reflection on it.

Currently I have to mark the types that need serialization code, using a custom `EnableSerialization` attribute.

Ideally, the generator would look at the compiled code (using static code analysis), identify the types that can possibly be passed to the generic `Serialize` and `Deserialize` methods and then generate code for those types. So, for example, if I have this somewhere in my code:

```cs
int x = 42;
Serialization.Serialize(x, new DataStream());
```

Then the code generator should pick up `int` as a type that needs serialization code.

Are there any recipes for this kind of endeavour, or is there anything in the .NET library or third-party libraries that can facilitate this?

(I have considered run-time code generation, but I'd prefer having it as a pre-processing step.)

Comment: Impossible? Might not be? Super-hard and extremely difficult and complex? For sure. You will have to decompile code, and consider all *possible* pathways through it, and track `<T>` usages across many types to be able to *safely* do this. Stay with the attribute, or some other marker concept. It is far far, FAR, from worth the effort of trying to do this and I'm not sure you would ever get it 100% right.

Comment: Is it possible for your code generator to correctly create serialization and deserialization code for *all* types? Could it be used at runtime, dynamically, on-the-fly generation?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen: It is meant for rather simple cases where it is sufficient to serialize all fields sequentially (non-public fields are set using reflection).
I now think that the ildasm.exe tool might be useful. It shows all calls to my generic methods including the generic arguments. So maybe calling ildasm.exe on my assembly with the output going to a text file and then scanning the text file for the method calls is a good idea.

Comment: ... of course it would still be a great challenge to track generic parameters across possibly many types ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `Mono.Reflection`, you can do the following:

```
HashSet<Type> types = new HashSet<Type>();
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"<Path>");

foreach (Module module in assembly.GetModules())
{
  foreach (Type type in module.GetTypes())
  {
    // GetMethodBody() should not be null since otherwise Disassembler.GetInstructions would throw an exception
    foreach (MethodInfo method in type.GetMethods().Where(m => m.GetMethodBody() != null))
    {
      foreach (Instruction instruction in Disassembler.GetInstructions(method))
      {
        // instruction.Operand being MethodInfo most probably means a call instrution.
        // Not sure if this always true
        MethodInfo called = instruction.Operand as MethodInfo;

        if (called != null && called.DeclaringType.Name.Equals("Serialization") && called.Name.Equals("Serialize"))
        {
          types.Add(called.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both `Disassembler` and `Instruction` are part of `Mono.Reflection`.
Now, you have all the type used passed to `Serialization.Serialize` in `types`.

Comment: Great, that seems to work just fine. Thank you! One might add BindingFlags.NonPublic etc. to the GetMethods() call in order to get all methods, not just the public ones.